# Is there a way to add angular directives from a db value within a component?

Tags: angular, dynamic, innerhtml

I am currently trying to create a web page designer from my angular app.
At the moment, I have a designer component which will be the parent. Within this one, I would like to create a component that would be able to use angular formated HTML.

In my DB, i would like to store a lot of differents HTML elements. By example :

`<span *ngIf="this.getDisplayedOptions().length > 0">Display default Values</span>`

After that, I would like to be able to create a component at runtime that would be able to make use of the ngIf by example. Like this:

`<app-elemennt [hmtl]="<span *ngIf="this.getDisplayedOptions().length > 0">Display default Values</span>">`

Is it possible or am I going the wrong way?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why don't you just create those components in Angular and store some reference in DB?

Comment: 1. Would it be performance advised? The idea is to have a lot of them (create a new component for title, text box, image, image carousel, etc)
2. How to call the component and how to store a reference in the db?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Storing html in dB and retrieving it  is not recommended it definitely has some performance issues.

Comment: Thanks. And for the 2nd question, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this using `[innerHTML]` binding, you should use the `DomSanitizer` as well, more precisely this  line of code:

```
 this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(yourDbHTML);
```

**UPDATE**

you can use [ngx-dynamic-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic-compiler) to achieve this, it works with angular 7+
check their demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dynamic-compiler)

Comment: Will that ngIf directive *ngIf="this.getDisplayedOptions().length > 0" work after sanitization also?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The compiler you gave me didn't seem to work but after some research, found that the same guy did another one which is working : [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codehint-ng/html-compiler)
I will give it a try, thanks for your help!